# Flutter NeverScrollableScrollPhysics pagenation not work

Tags: flutter, gridview, nestedscrollview

I am trying to bind `NestedScrollView` and `GridView` with pagenation.

However, I put `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in the `GridView`, the pagenation function does not work.

I guess it is caused by scrollcontroller.

How can I solve this problem?

I will attach my code.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  //infinite scroll
  List<DocumentSnapshot> products = []; // stores fetched products
  bool isLoading = false; // track if products fetching
  bool hasMore = true; // flag for more products available or not
  int documentLimit = 20; // documents to be fetched per request
  DocumentSnapshot
  lastDocument; // flag for last document from where next 10 records to be fetched
  ScrollController _scrollController =
  ScrollController(); // listener for listview scrolling

  @override
  void initState() {
    getProducts();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
      double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
      double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20;
      if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= delta) {
        getProducts();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  getProducts() async {
    //...
    //get items from firebase
    //...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.backgroundwhite,
          title: Image(
            width: 132.0,
            height: 40.0,
            image: AssetImage('images/logo_horiz.png'),
          ),          
        ),
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, isScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "다른 유저가 키우는",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                  fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                            ),
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5.0)),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  "율마",
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 24.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "가 궁금하신가요?",
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 24.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                      fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 25.0)),
                            Container(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 46,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.lightGrey,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => SearchPage()),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Icon(Icons.search,
                                            size: 30.0, color: Colors.black12),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding:
                                          const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          "율마",
                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20.0,
                                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .colorScheme
                                                  .textBlack,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                              fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ))),
                          ]),
                    ),
                  ]))
            ];
          },
          body: LayoutBuilder(
              builder:(BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
                return ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
                    ),
                    child: IntrinsicHeight(
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            // this will host our Tab Views
                              child: GridView.builder(
//                                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                                    childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 1.0),
                                controller: _scrollController,
                                itemCount: products.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return _buildListItem(context, products[index]);
                                },
                              )),
                        ])));
              }),
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, item) {
    return Hero(
      tag: item.documentID,
      child: Material(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPostPage(item)),
            );
          },
          child: Image.network(item['imageUrls'][0]['url'], fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! finally I have solved this problem using `CustomScrollView` instead of `NestedScrollview`.

In addition, I wraped the `CustomScrollView` as `LayoutBuilder`.

Hense the final code of the body part of `Scaffold` is following:

```
LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
        return ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
            ),
            child: CustomScrollView(
//              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _scrollController,
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                        _buildHeader()
                      ])),
                  SliverGrid(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 1.0),
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return _buildListItem(context, products[index]);
                    },
                    childCount: products.length,
                  ),
                )
              ]
            )
        );
      }),
```

I hope it would be helpful for you!